# How can I achieve 'incremental backup with 1 hour timing' period in mysql using Ansible Playbook based on binlog?

Tags: mysql, ansible, database-backups, mysql-backup

I have two servers. master and slave which moderated for replication. replication process is working good. Here I wants to use "incremental dump" option for every one hour and upload that to s3 bucket or another server or local machine(control machine). From the mysql documentations I have a confident to done this using binlogfile. But I have no idea where from I start.

I am following the steps which are given below. But I dont know how the binlog file changing only equivalent of incremental dump even it have all the queries what we done in the database.

```
I wants to take dump from slave db. How that will take dump exactly one hour time period. How can I achieve that?
```

my replication code is here.

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "CREATE TABLE db_test.mytable (name VARCHAR(100));"
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "INSERT INTO db_test.mytable (name) VALUES ('ANSIBLE');"
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;"
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "SHOW MASTER STATUS;"
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "unlock tables;"
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "drop database db_test;"
sudo mysql -uroot -p'Pass@123' --connect-expired-password -e "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_test.mytable;"
-get master
-adding values to dummy host
-changemaster using dummyhost value 
-starting slave
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

- `Flush binary logs` [new binary log file created]
- By using `binlog.index` file, found previous binary file. Copied that file to where I want to upload. That is the dump file and I got data from that file got restore.
- File saved by current timestamp name value.
- Automation done by using `crontab -e` file.
- `1 */1 * * *` is the value used for time scheduling.[every first minute of an hour]